# Get value Based on Name

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework, and i am not getting `value` of a column based on `name` column. Little bit confusing but see code and table structure you can understand.

**Table Structure:**

[image]

**My Model:**

```
function get_twitter_code(){
    $query=$this->db->select('name');
    $query=$this->db->from('preferences');
    $query=$this->db->where('name','tweets_code');
    return $this->db->get()->row();
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
$data['twitter_code']=$this->Home_model->get_twitter_code();
```

**My View:**

```
<?php echo $twitter_code;?>
```

**Error:**

> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

But When i change this line `return $this->db->get()->row();` to `return $this->db->get()->result_array();`, then following error shows.

> Message: Array to string conversion

I want to get to the `value` of `name` where `name='tweets_code'`.
I adds the manually the name filed in database `tweets_code` and then add value using html form against `tweets_code` now problem is i am not getting value of `tweets_code`.

Comment: `$this->db->get()->result_array()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->db->get()->row();
```

, but change your controller:

```
$data['twitter_code']=$this->Home_model->get_twitter_code()->name;
```

Comment: `$this->db->select('name');` should be `$this->db->select('value');` if you're looking to return the value

Comment: @iainn now this error if change as you said. **Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$name**

Comment: Change `->name` to `->value` as well - if you're not fetching the name then you shouldn't be referring to it in the code.

Comment: @Hamza Zafeer change value: $this->Home_model->get_twitter_code()->value; =)

Comment: Solved. get desired result. can you please explain this line. `Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$name`

Comment: Function ->row() return one row like obgect. When you code [code]$this->db->select('name');[/code] you get object like this: {name:'Same name'}. then you change sepect paran, your object had change too  {value:'Same value'}.